# Upload image to the server blackberry 10 qml

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

i need to upload the image to the server i have used file picker to fetch the image, i have attached my  sample code but its not working

my file picker code

```
                        `   Button {
                    text: "Change Profile Image"
                    onClicked {
                         filePicker.open();
                    }                   
                       attachedObjects: [
                        FilePicker {
                            id: filePicker
                            property string selectedFile
                            type: FileType.Picture
                            onFileSelected: {
                                selectedFile = selectedFiles[0]
                                image.imageSource = selectedFile
                                   _settings.showToast( selectedFile);
                                  _settings.isUpdate(selectedFile);
                            }
                        }
                   ]`
```

my image update code in c++

```
             `void Settings::isUpdate(QString selectedFile){


    QString path("asset:///Icon/mess.jpg");

    //php script that receives the image

    QNetworkRequest requete(QUrl("http://192.168.1.176:2222/api?type=uploadimages&name=IMG_00000001.jpg&pin=123456")); //our server with php-script

    QByteArray boundary = "-------------------------87142694621188";
    QFile file(path);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        qDebug()<<"erreur read image";
        return;
    }
    QByteArray fileContent(file.readAll());
    QByteArray data = "--" + boundary + "\r\n";
    data += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"data\"; filename=\"IMG_00000001.jpg\";\r\n";
    data += "Content-Type: image/jpg\r\n\r\n" + fileContent + "\r\n";
    data += "--" + boundary + "--\r\n";

    requete.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
    requete.setRawHeader("Content-Length", QString::number(data.size()).toAscii());
    file.close();
    qDebug() <<"data"<< data.size();
    QNetworkAccessManager *am = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QNetworkReply *reply = am->post(requete,"&data="+data);
    QObject::connect(am, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
```

}

```
       void Settings::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
          {
         reply->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
         if(reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
           {
                QByteArray str=(reply->readAll());
                 QString response = QString::fromUtf8(str.data(), str.size());
                   qDebug()<<" re "<<response;
                      }

                      else
                       qDebug()<<"error response server";
                      }`
```

i can able to get response,but can't able to upload the image in the server

thanks

Comment: Start by asking a question: you asked for help but did not tell us what's happened. By the way, you should upload directly an QIODevice instead of a QByteArray for better memory performance

Comment: i can able to get the response from the url,but can't able to upload the image

Comment: Try to do a am->post with directly an QIODevice or the byteArray. The size header should be automatically generated

Comment: can u able to elaborate,

Comment: https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#post

Answer (score 0):

```
QString body = "" ;

const QUrl url("http://someurl.to/make/the/post" );
 QHttpMultiPart *multiPart = new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);
 QHttpPart textPartData;
 body = "" ;
 QTextStream(&body) << "";
 textPartData.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/json; charset=utf-8");
 textPartData.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"data\""));
 textPartData.setBody(body.toAscii());

     for(int i=0; i< number_of_files_to_send ; i++){
             QHttpPart imagePart;
             QString header_body = "";
             QTextStream(&header_body) << "form-data; name=\"" << name_of_the_file << "\"; filename=\"" << name_of_the_file << ".jpg\"" ;
             imagePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant(header_body));
             imagePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QVariant("image/jpeg"));

             //prepare file for upload
             QString filepath;
             QTextStream(&filepath) << FunkyPigeonBlackberry::getInstance()->dataModelProductDetails()->custom_image(i).value("cut_image").toString();

             // pack the new file
             QFile *file = new QFile(filepath);
             file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
             imagePart.setBodyDevice(file);
             file->setParent(multiPart); // we cannot delete the file now, so delete it with the multiPart
             multiPart->append(imagePart);
     }

 multiPart->append(textPartData);
 multiPart->append(textPartProductDetails);
 multiPart->append(textPartDataDelivery);


 QNetworkRequest request(url);

 QNetworkReply* reply = m_networkAccessManager->post(request, multiPart);
 connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onNetworkResponse()));
```